# How to use YEARFRAC in Oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, function

I want to implement one logic of Excel sheet in Oracle database.

I'm using `YEARFRAC()` in Oracle in a stored procedure but I am getting error as:

> Error(166,22): PLS-00201: identifier 'YEARFRAC' must be declared

Here is my code:

```
v_STD_REVISED_AMT := YEARFRAC('01-04-2016', V_FINALSRDATE, 'dd-mm-yy');
```

How can I implement this, or is there any other way to implement `YEARFRAC` in Oracle?

### Update

My second parameter value is `07-05-2018`

Comment: Based on the Excel help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8 the third paramater to `yearfrac` is a number that specifies the basis of the calculation.  I'm not sure what basis you intend for your calculation or if you really need to create an Oracle function that handles all the different basis parameters that `yearfrac` does.

Comment: You'd need to create it.  Creating it requires a set of requirements which is what I'm trying to understand.  The optional third argument in Excel completely changes how the calculation is done so if you need to support all the possible arguments, that makes the problem much larger.  If you only need to support one method of calculation, that makes things simpler.  If you don't need to exactly match Excel and just want a reasonable method of getting a fractional year, the question is pretty easy.

Comment: @JustinCave: I have updated my question with parameter values. Let's try the second one the one which gives a simple fractional year.

Comment: OK.  So you only want to support one method of calculation?  Which of the 5 methods do you need to use?

Comment: @hud Check the link to the `YEARFRAC` Excel documentation in my answer; the 3rd argument is a number with defines which of 5 different basis the calculation is made upon.

Comment: Are you doing this just for learning PL/SQL and Oracle SQL, or do you plan to use this calculation in actual work? If it's for actual work (either to report investment returns or to compute income tax, or to determine how to split interest between buyer and seller, etc.) you shouldn't use a function you create from scratch, while lacking the skills to do so correctly. You may get into various kinds of regulatory trouble (with the tax authorities, investment authorities, investors, etc.) Oracle sells - for big bucks I assume - modules that do such calculations out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YEARFRAC` is an Excel function (and other supporting spreadsheets).

As your error states:

> ```
> Error(166,22): PLS-00201: identifier 'YEARFRAC' must be declared
> ```

The `YEARFRAC` function is not defined in Oracle and you cannot use it.

If you want something equivalent then you will need to write a custom function.

*(Note: The [Excel function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8) does not, with the default 3rd parameter, calculate the actual number of days between the dates and for the year but uses the US (NASD) 30/360 method of counting days; if you naively just count days then the output will not match Excel.)*

---

If you want the default US (NADS) 30/360 behaviour for `YEARFRAC` then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION YEARFRAC(
  start_date IN DATE,
  end_date   IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.ver_le_11 $THEN
  $ELSE
    PRAGMA UDF;
  $END
  y1 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM start_date);
  m1 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date);
  d1 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(DAY   FROM start_date);
  y2 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM end_date);
  m2 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM end_date);
  d2 PLS_INTEGER := EXTRACT(DAY   FROM end_date);
BEGIN
  IF m1 = 2 AND TRUNC(start_date) = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(start_date)) THEN
    IF m2 = 2 AND TRUNC(end_date) = LAST_DAY(TRUNC(end_date)) THEN
      d2 := 30;
    END IF;
    d1 := 30;
  END IF;
  IF d2 = 31 AND d1 >= 30 THEN
    d2 := 30;
  END IF;
  IF d1 = 31 THEN
    d1 := 30;
  END IF;
  RETURN (360*(y2-y1)+30*(m2-m1)+d2-d1)/360;
END yearfrac;
/
```

Then:

```sql
WITH date_range ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-07', DATE '2021-07-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-12-31' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       yearfrac( start_date, end_date )
FROM   date_range
```

Outputs:

> | START_DATE | END_DATE | YEARFRAC_DAYS30_360 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 07-JAN-21 | 07-JUL-21 | 0.5 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 01-FEB-21 | 0.0833333333333333 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 30-DEC-21 | 0.997222222222222 |
> | 01-JAN-21 | 31-DEC-21 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbc3569ef9ab203333f6d1c6b9b7cc72)*